# How to print this array?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to print an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

```
public char[] createArray() {        
  char[] s;        
  s = new char[26];

  for ( int i=0; i<26; i++ ) {    
    s[i] = (char) (’A’ + i);   
  }            
  return s;

  // how to print s?

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print is as an array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

if you want to print as a String

```
System.out.println(new String(s));
```

btw you can write

```
char[] s = new char['Z' - 'A' + 1];
for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
   s[ch - 'A'] = ch;
```

Comment: Thanks, could you also let me know what is the meaning of very first line.. Thanks.

Comment: From the Javadoc `Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(char). Returns "null" if a is null.`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`Arrays.toString(s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) and print the resulting `String`.